# Drupal - Current page, other language

Tags: drupal, localization, internationalization

i've found this code :

```
<?php global $language; ?>
<?php global $theme_path; ?>

<ul class="language-switcher-locale-url">
    <?php $languages = language_list() ?>
    <?php foreach($languages as $lang): ?>
    <?php $active = $language->language == $lang->language ? " active" : ""; ?>
    <li class="<?php echo $lang->language ?><?php echo $active ?>">
        <a href="/<?php echo $lang->prefix ?>">
            <img src="/<?php echo $theme_path ?>/images/flags/<?php echo $lang->language ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $lang->language ?>"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

This redirects me from `mywebsite.com/de/current_page` to the selected language ex. `mywebsite.com/en`

what can i do for my code to redirects me to `mywebsite.com/en/current_page`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using the [url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) and [request_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/request_path/7) function that Drupal provides, perhaps something like this would work:

```
<?php global $language; global $theme_path; $languages = language_list() ?>

<ul class="language-switcher-locale-url">                                                                                                                                                                           
  <?php foreach($languages as $lang): ?>
    <?php $active = $language->language == $lang->language ? " active" : ""; ?>
    <li class="<?php echo $lang->language ?><?php echo $active ?>">
      <a href="<?php echo url(request_path(), array('language' => $lang)); ?>">
        <img src="/<?php echo $theme_path ?>/images/flags/<?php echo $lang->language ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $lang->language ?>"/>
      </a>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nah it didn't work , it's just redirecting to the actual page in current language

Comment: Ah, sorry, after reading the url documentation I realized that the language option wants a language object, not a language ID. I updated the code accordingly.Try it now. :)

Comment: again it didnt work, redirect to actual page in current language like , from mywebsite.com/en/content-english to mywebsite.com/en/de/content-english